# Dojo Datagrid open first cell of new item for editing

Tags: datagrid, dojo, grid

I am trying to use doStartEdit(inCell, inRowIndex) function of datagrid to open first cell of newly added row for editing in dojo 1.9 Enhanced grid, but the function does not work.
It says in api that the arguments should be:
inCell - object of a cell (I get it with getCell() function)
inRowIndex - index number of a row
I am not sure because arguments are not clearly described in the api, I tried to look at the same variable descriptions near other grid functions.

I tried other variations of arguments, like cell number insted of object, and row object instead of row index. None of them worked. Is it a bug? Or I just use it in wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to do is focus and set a cell for editing by the user then below should work for you.. that will focus on column 1 row 1.

```
grid.edit.setEditCell(grid.getCell(0),0)
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/Pjzef/